# Heatsink near fan doesn't even warm

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

I have an issue with my laptop, it's always overheat, I have already clean the area of the processor and heatsink that will be the place where I put the thermal paste, before applying them, but whenever I use the laptop it's always in overheat situation.

My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad 100 14 IBD, Im running at

> Windows 10 Home 64 bits
> Intel i3 5005u
> RAM DDR3L 2GB on board + DDR3L 4GB Kingston KVR16S11/4
> SSD SATA 256GB

When I using the laptop on overheat situation, the air flow that came out from the fan doesn't even feel warm, then I check the heatsink, it's was super hot, but the heatsink near the fan doesn't even hot, I just wonder why this could happens, I already tried to clean the paste thermal area, clean the fan and even use an vacumm cooler.

Comment: A CPU heatsink is supposed to be warm.  What behavior exactly made you believe your system is overheating?

Comment: Is the fan running?  Did you connect it properly?  See:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qh0SA3LB6o   . Then make sure it was put together properly.

Comment: the heatsink that near the fan, it doesn't even warm, as the youtube video that @john mention, the heatsink shape like a pipe that curved long into the fan exhaust. I'm using core temp, then detect that the core temperature reach 100 deg celciuls.

Comment: While the heatsink part above the processor are hot, its seems like the heat doesn't transferred through the heatsink pipe

Comment: I playing few game like dota 2, which in low preset usually hits 40fps, but it constanly dropping from 40fps i count about 2-4 seconds its drop to 2-10fps, after 5-12 seconds it up again to 20-40fps and will drop again after 2-4 seconds. Not only on the game, every time my processor reach 100% usage about 2-6 seconds, its will became really laggy

Comment: It appears you should get the computer serviced at a local repair shop. The CPU can get hot from load, but (via the fan), heat should transfer out. .

Answer (score 0):

> *While the heatsink part above the processor are hot, its seems like the heat doesn't transferred through the heatsink pipe*

It appears that heatsink may be defective; for the procedure to check/replace the heatsink cooling pipe(s), see:  [Dell Precision 7510 overheating heatsink diagnostics (Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5HlScq8qD0)